# best way to pass dates as query params

Tags: rest, http

What is the "industry standard" to format a date as a query param?

My initial thoughts are to just use the HTML input format for dates: `YYYY-MM-DD` as a string.

Answer (score 4):

`YYYY-MM-DD` is exactly the recommended date format by `ISO 8601`.

For mor information see [ISO 8601 Date and time format](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html)